How to validate the builder function integration in chain_spec file?
I am performing an upgrade of the Polkadot version from 1.8 to 1.9, which involves updating the from_genesis function to the builder function in the chain_spec file.
I generated one chain spec without integrating the builder function (referred to as old_chain_spec). After integrating the builder function, I generated another chain spec (referred to as new_chain_spec).
I then compared all fields between the old_chain_spec and new_chain_spec. While all fields are identical, I noticed that the code field is different.
Is this approach of comparing both chain specs correct? If so, could you explain why the code field differs between the two specs?

Becase you just upgraded a lot of code, both in the runtime definition, the pallets and the internals of all of them. That implies now the compiled wasm code will be different, since the code it is based on is different as well.
